# Python dictionary to pandas dataframe missing key values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, pypdf

I'm using Python 3.8 on windows 64.

I used PyPDF2 to find strings. I defined these values into dictionary using the code below:

```
keys=range(7)
values = (Docket, Date, CC, Owner, Scope, Crew, Additional)
dict_convert = dict(zip(keys,values))
print(dict_convert)
```

dict_convert print is below and shows range=7 (keys 0 to 6)

```
{0: '149623', 1: '21/10/19', 2: 'UTILITIES', 3: 'Camille .', 4: '008-lilyÞeld Rd-grove To Ryan-stop Slow-134-01, Rol_1268472_20190923-161408, ', 5: '5', 6: 'None'}
```

When I parse this into Pandas DataFrame only keys 0 to 4 are output. Any ideas why? Thanks in advance.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_convert, orient='index',dtype=None)
print(df.head())

                                                   0
0                                             149623
1                                           21/10/19
2                                          UTILITIES
3                                          Camille .
4  008-lilyÞeld Rd-grove To Ryan-stop Slow-134-01...
```

Comment: Because `print(df.head())`  filter first 5 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because if use [`DataFrame.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html) it filter first 5 rows.

If want see all data in small DataFrame:

```
print(df)
```

If there is more rows and added `...` use:

```
#temporaly display all rows
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', -1):
    print (df)
```